# momentjs keep getting the following error moment.js:Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to integrate maddhatter laravel-fullcalendar into a laravel app, I have the calendar working on most browsers but it fails on Internet Exprorer, when I do an inspect I get the deprecation warning.

My array looks like this:

```js
$('#calendar-wean15RN').fullCalendar({
  "header":{
     "left":"prev,next today",
     "center":"title",
     "right":"month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
  },
  "eventLimit":true,
  "defaultDate":"Apr 2017",
  "eventColor":"#3c8dbc !important",
  "eventBackgroundColor":"#3c8dbc !important",
  "eventBorderColor":"#3c8dbc",
  "eventTextColor":"#fff !important",
  "events":[{
    "id":"1557",
    "title":"xxx \nHrs worked:6.00",
    "allDay":"true",
    "start":"2017-04-03T09:00:00+00:00",
    "end":"2017-04-03T15:00:00+00:00",
    "url":"\/timesheet\/1557\/edit"
  }]
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The full error looks like this

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true, _l: undefined, _i: Apr 2017, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (js/moment.js:314:94)
    at configFromString (js/moment.js:2172:11)
    at configFromInput (js/moment.js:2541:9)
    at prepareConfig (js/moment.js:2524:9)
    at createFromConfig (js/moment.js:2491:40)
    at createLocalOrUTC (js/moment.js:2578:12)
    at Function.createUTC [as utc] (js/moment.js:81:12)
    at makeMoment (js/fullcalendar.js:1197:21)
    at FC.moment.parseZone (js/fullcalendar.js:1154:9)
    at constructor.moment (js/fullcalendar.js:11795:30)
warn @ moment.js:287
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"defaultDate":"Apr 2017"` to `"defaultDate":moment("Apr 2017", "MMM YYYY")`.

FullCalendar docs state the [`defaultDate`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) 's type is Moment.

As the warning says: value provided (`"Apr 2017"`) is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format; so you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing function.

Answer (score 0):

As it says here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/
defaultDate should also be an ISO8601 date string.

```
$('#calendar-wean15RN').fullCalendar(
    {"header":{"left":"prev,next today","center":"title","right":"month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"},"eventLimit":true,"defaultDate":"2017-04-03T09:00:00+00:00","eventColor":"#3c8dbc !important","eventBackgroundColor":"#3c8dbc !important","eventBorderColor":"#3c8dbc","eventTextColor":"#fff !important","events":[{"id":"1557","title":"xxx \nHrs worked:6.00","allDay":"true","start":"2017-04-03T09:00:00+00:00","end":"2017-04-03T15:00:00+00:00","url":"\/timesheet\/1557\/edit"}]
}
```